# Using CE Images bulk tag for responsive images syntax

Tags: ce-image, responsive-images

I know how to use a CE Images tag pair to generate a one-off example of responsive images syntax from an image (the image being represented by the custom field {base_pic} in the following example):

```
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{base_pic}" width="400"}
    <img 
        src="{made}" 
        alt="my alt text" 
        title="my title" 
        srcset="
            {exp:ce_img:single src="{base_pic}" width="250" url_only="yes"} 250w,
            {exp:ce_img:single src="{base_pic}" width="600" url_only="yes"} 600w,
            {exp:ce_img:single src="{base_pic}" width="1200" url_only="yes"} 1200w"
        sizes="
            (min-width: 1110px) 625px,
            (min-width: 768px) 56vw,
            (min-width: 321px) 86vw,
            258px"
        >
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
```

What I am struggling with is how to generate such syntax for multiple images using the ce_img:bulk tag (so I can use it to process an Expresso rich text field). I tried using the output= parameter, but that failed because of course it requires me to specify the output markup as the parameter's value, and you can't put a ce_img:single tag inside another ce_img tag's parameter.

AFAICT I can't just put the img markup between the opening and closing tags like I did with the example above, because that's where the entire {expresso_field} needs to go.

I'm very much a CE Image noob and am getting lost amid the plethora of available options parameter and tag options (an embarrassment of riches!), so I'm confident that I'm just missing something and it can be done somehow. But I'm just not seeing it, so can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: I"m not sure that this is possible. Have you tried asking for support from Causing Effect on their devot:ee forum?

Comment: I have. I'll see what that turns up. But if anyone has a solution here, do chime in!

Comment: FWIW here is the thread about this on Devot-EE: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-image/viewthread/15191